# Can I delete blk*.dat files?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, pruning

Since bitcoin validates blockchain by the hash of older blocks recursively; Can I just keep the last blk*.dat file and delete the rest while the bitcoin core is downloading and validating the blockchain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, if you *manually* delete these files, Bitcoin Core will notice the missing files and abort.

However, Bitcoin Core does have functionality to discard blocks after validating them: pruning. You can enable pruning by setting `prune=<n>` in your `bitcoin.conf` file or by passing `-prune=<n>` to `bitcoind` on startup.

Check `bitcoind -h` for more information, but briefly:

- `prune=1` allows for manually deleting blocks using the `pruneblockchain` rpc
- `prune=<some number >= 550>` enables your node to automatically delete blocks to keep the size, measured in MiB, less than the number specified

A few things to keep in mind when pruning:

- You cannot run `txindex` while pruning, so you won't be able to use your node to lookup specific transactions
- If you ever want to turn pruning off, you will need to re-download the entire blockchain

Comment: And to be clear: no, you can't just delete the files manually. Bitcoin Core will notice the files are missing and abort.